# Return multiple comma separate values via lookup in Google sheets / Excel

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for some help in creating a query in Google sheets that will look up a list of words (C2:C17) and see if those words appear in paragraphs of text in cells A2:A10. The result should see a comma separated list of words in column E and I'd like to be able to drag the query down through E2, E3, E4, etc.

Whilst it's ideal to do this in Googlesheets, i'd be happy with an Excel formula too.

Below is a sample spreadsheet to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

Samlple sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DmafyX6xj7QRut5L2aTRMLGx0dhE-LKIgAcSpxE4OHs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel if one has TEXTJOIN in their version:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$18,A2)),$C$2:$C$18,""))
```

Depending on version this may need to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

I think(untested) this for GoogleSheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$18,A2)),$C$2:$C$18,"")))
```

[image]